# Setting __attribute__((used)) to C variable/constant has no effect

Tags: c, gcc, arm, nxp-microcontroller

On ARM GCC (plain C code), when I declare a constant as in

```
__attribute__((used,section(".rodata.$AppID")))
const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

and **I don't refer to it in the code**, it's **optimized out**, and listed in *Discarded input sections* on map file.
It's included in binary output only if I refer to it, somewhere else in the sources.

Shouldn't the "`used`" tag alone be enough? In the GCC manual ([6.34.1 Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)) I read:

> used
>
> This attribute, attached to a variable with static storage, means that the variable must be emitted even if it appears that the variable is not referenced.

*The meaning is to have it at a fixed memory address, in the specified section, for a separate application to check for it*

I'm running ARM GCC as provided with NXP MCUXpresso 11.1, reporting verbose version as

```
GNU C17 (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2019-q3-update) version 8.3.1 20190703 (release) [gcc-8-branch revision 273027] (arm-none-eabi)
compiled by GNU C version 5.3.1 20160211, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP
```

Comment: The map file you reference, is it the one of the linker? -- Did you look into the object file by `objdump`, is the variable included?

Comment: @thebusybee The compiler issues a warning for "../src/protocol.c:150:23: warning: unused variable 'ApplicationID' [-Wunused-variable]
  extern const uint8_t ApplicationID[16];", the linker lists it in discarded sections. Its value is not emitted, so not present when exporting from elf with objcopy/objdump to any format. I would be quite surprised as well, if after being tagged as 'unused'/'discarded' it was still in ELF

Comment: An error in my comment above: the compiler warning was related to just an "extern" declaration I added, without a reference to it. So the what's worth is from the comment on the linker onwards.
As said, if I add any valid reference to variable (like assigning it), linker lists it on map file, and it becomes present in ELF output

Comment: OK, we now have, correct me if I'm wrong: The compiler is (mostly) happy, the compiled object file contains the variable eventhough it is unused, but it is flagged as **unused**. Consequently the linkers discards it, reports this in its map file, and the variable is not in the resulting binary.

Comment: Well, then you need to look into the linker's options. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with them, and I'm too busy these times to do it myself. -- Another idea: Do you use a linker script? If so, you might like to extend it to keep the section. If not, it might be the time to copy the used default script, and to edit and to use that copy.

Comment: Maybe the LD option "--gc-sections" is pruning too much, even if I flagged the variable as "used". Though I can't avoid it, or the system libraries throw everything in a mayhem.
Linker script is nicely managed by the Eclipse IDE, (maybe) I could force a KEEP on that section, hand crafting it. However I liked the idea to explain everything in source code with __attribute__. Then again I will prefer resorting to a dummy reference, than intervening in linker script (as less visible).
Browsed quickly LD options, but I can't see anything appropriate to feed on cmd line...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Shouldn't the "used" tag alone be enough?

It is not sufficient, and it is not necessary. It is not relevant.

As per the GCC documentation that you have quoted, attribute `used` is
applicable to definitions of *static* variables. And as an answer that is now
deleted by the author pointed out, your `ApplicationID` is not static, so attribute `used`
has no effect.

Here:

```
/* app_id_extern.c */

#include <stdint.h>

const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

we have `ApplicationID` defined, by default, as an `extern` variable. The default storage class
of a filescope variable, like `ApplicationID`, is `extern`. The compiler will
accordingly generate an object file in which the definition of `ApplicationID`
is exposed for linkage, as we can see:

```
$ gcc -c app_id_extern.c
$ readelf -s app_id_extern.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     ...
     9: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 ApplicationID
```

In the object file, `ApplicationID` is a 16-byte `GLOBAL` symbol in section #4
(which in this case happens to be `.rodata`). The `GLOBAL` binding means that the static linker can see this symbol.

And here:

```
/* app_id_static.c */

#include <stdint.h>

static const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

we have `ApplicationID` explicitly defined as a `static` variable. The compiler
will accordingly generate an object file in which the definition of `ApplicationID`
is *not* exposed for linkage, as we can also see:

```
$ gcc -c app_id_static.c
$ readelf -s app_id_static.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     ...
     6: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 ApplicationID
     ...
```

In this object file, `ApplicationID` is a 16-byte `LOCAL` symbol in the `.rodata` section
The `LOCAL` binding means that the static linker *cannot* see this symbol.

The compiler will *always* emit in the object file a definition of an `extern` variable,
like that of `ApplicationID` in `app_id_extern.c`, even if that definition is not
referenced in the object file, because the external definition will be available to
the linker, and therefore might by be referenced at linktime from other object files, for all that
the compiler can possibly know.

But if a variable is `static`, then the compiler knows that its definition is unavailable
for linkage. So if it can determine that the definition is not referenced within the
object file itself, it may conclude that the definition is redundant and not emit it
in the object file at all. Like so:

```
$ gcc -O1 -c app_id_static.c
```

This time, we ask the compiler to perform minimal optimizations. And then

```
$ readelf -s app_id_static.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS app_id_static.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
```

the unreferenced definition of `ApplicationID` is no longer present in the object file
*at all*. It was optimized out.

Now for certain unusual applications we may want the compiler to emit the definition
of a symbol in an object file that does not refer to it, *and* conceal it from the static linker. That is
where attribute `used` comes into play:

```
/* app_id_static_used .c */

#include <stdint.h>

static const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] __attribute__((used,section(".rodata.$AppID"))) = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

Once again we compile with -O1 optimization:

```
$ gcc -O1 -c app_id_static_used.c
$ readelf -s app_id_static_used.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     ...
     6: 0000000000000000    16 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 ApplicationID
     ...
```

But this time, thanks to attribute `used`, the `LOCAL` definition of `ApplicationID`
reappears in section #4 (which in this object file is `.rodata.$AppID`)

That is how attribute `used` works. It affects the behaviour of the compiler: it has no
influence on the linker.

We haven't done any linkage yet. Let's do some now.

```
/* hello_world.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!")
    return 0;
}
```

This program makes no reference to `ApplicationID`, but we'll input `app_id_static_used.o`
to the linkage regardless:

```
$ gcc -O1 -c hello_world.c
$ gcc -o hello hello_world.o app_id_static_used.o -Wl,-gc-sections,-Map=mapfile.txt
```

In the linkage, I have asked for unused input sections to be dropped, and for a mapfile
to be output (`-Wl,-gc-sections,-Map=mapfile.txt`)

In the mapfile we find:

**Mapfile.txt**

```
...
Discarded input sections
  ...
  .rodata.$AppID
                0x0000000000000000       0x10 app_id_static_used.o
  ...
```

The linker has discarded section `.rodata.$AppID` input from `app_id_static_used.o`
because no symbol defined in that section is referenced in the program. With
attribute `used`, we compelled the compiler to emit the definition of that `static` symbol
in `app_id_static_used.o`. That doesn't compell the linker to need it, or keep
it in the executable.

In we switch from `app_id_static_used.c` to:

```
/* app_id_extern_used.c */

#include <stdint.h>

const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] __attribute__((used,section(".rodata.$AppID"))) = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

then we're doing what you did, applying attribute `used` to an `extern` definition. Attribute
`used` has no effect in that case, because the compiler is bound to emit the `extern`
definition in any case. And the linker will *still* discard the `.rodata.$AppID` input section from the
executable if the program does not refer to anything in it.

So far, your app-id source file might as well be:

```
/* app_id_extern_section.c */

#include <stdint.h>

const uint8_t   ApplicationID[16] __attribute__((section(".rodata.$AppID"))) = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

And what you then need to do is inform *the linker* that you want the definition of
the symbol `ApplicationID` kept, even if it is not referenced by your program, and
if even if unused sections are dropped.

To achieve that, use the linker option `--undefined=ApplicationID`. This will
direct the linker to assume from the start that the linkage of your program
has encountered an undefined reference to `ApplicationID` and compel the linker
to find and link its definition, if any input file provides one. Thus:

```
$ gcc -O1 -c app_id_extern_section.c
$ gcc -o hello hello_world.o app_id_extern_section.o -Wl,-gc-sections,--undefined=ApplicationID
```

Now the program contains the definition of `ApplicationID`, despite not referring to it:

```
$ readelf -s hello | grep ApplicationID
    58: 0000000000002010    16 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   18 ApplicationID
```

Section #18 is the `.rodata` section of the program:

```
$ readelf --sections hello | grep '.rodata'
  [18] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000002000  00002000
```

Lastly, note that the input section `.rodata.$AppID` from `app_id_extern_section.o`
has been merged into the output section `.rodata`, because the linker's default
linker script specifies:

```
.rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
```

i.e. all input sections matching `.rodata`, `.rodata.*` or `.gnu.linkonce.r.*`
will be output to `.rodata`. This means that even:

```
__attribute__((section(".rodata.$AppID")))
```

is redundant. So the app-id source file might as well simply be the one
I started with, `app_id_extern.c`, and the linkage option `--undefined=ApplicationID`
is all that is necessary to keep the unreferenced symbol in the program. Unless
your linker is different in that respect you will find the same.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer and analysis: this solves my question!
I don't know what made me think that the "used" attribute could flag a behavior for linker as well, maybe I've seen it used somewhere along with "section" specifier and interpreted it the wrong way.
Forgive me if I will extremely simplify it with "use --undefined=xxx with linker" :D

Comment: Just a separate note on section(".rodata.$AppID"): I still need it, as my data has to located at a __fixed__ memory address, not allocated with the rest of ".rodata" of the application.

Comment: @LuC And are you now finding that your linker *does* merge it into `.rodata` in the executable, or is it remaining distinct as you want?

Comment: It's emitted in the separate .rodata.$AppID, as I expected, at a fixed Flash memory address. I've also found what made me think that attribute "used" was meaningful: it's used by NXP code itself, to declare the interrupt vectors section -- again, this is extern storage, global to the whole application, so it's meaningless even in their code. Note however that they have a KEEP directive in linker script for vectors sections, so even if "used" is... useless, their result is fine

Comment: Static storage != static variables. Static storage means static lifetime. This includes global as well as static variables. And `--undefined`` should actually not help in the use case mentioned - and does not on ARM in my experience. Either it has changed or there is a bug in the x86 implementation.